# Split pcap on multiple IP addresses

Tags: pcap, tcpdump

I have a large pcap file that I am trying to split, and I have a list of IP addresses. I would like to split the pcap into two smaller pcaps. One pcap will include all the packets with src equal to one of the IP addresses in my list, and one pcap will include everything else (dest equal to one of the listed IP addresses). In other words, one pcap includes all packets flowing into those machines, and one pcap includes all packets flowing out of those machines. All packets will have either src or dest equal to one of the listed IPs. Can this be done using tcpdump? I would really prefer to use tcpdump since it will be a lot of overhead for me to install any other tools on the Linux machine I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

First use `tcpdump -w FILE` in order to record the packet flow:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -s0 -n -e -w /tmp/w.pcap
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
^C123 packets captured
126 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Then use `tcpdump -r FILE` to read it.

```
$ tcpdump -n -r /tmp/w.pcap | head
20:48:38.498793 IP 192.168.250.10.22 > 192.168.250.1.49434: Flags [P.], seq 240912301:240912433, ack 2683174485, win 724, options [nop,nop,TS val 8711083 ecr 381715459], length 132
20:48:38.498968 IP 192.168.250.1.49434 > 192.168.250.10.22: Flags [.], ack 132, win 8183, options [nop,nop,TS val 381715490 ecr 8711083], length 0
20:48:40.945504 IP 192.168.250.10.68 > 192.168.250.254.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:0c:29:48:aa:d6, length 300
20:48:40.946062 IP 192.168.250.254.67 > 192.168.250.10.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300
20:48:41.045549 IP 192.168.250.10.33131 > 109.231.72.179.22: Flags [S], seq 724706181, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 8711720 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
20:48:42.539655 IP 192.168.250.1.49471 > 192.168.250.10.22: Flags [S], seq 3387751538, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 4,nop,nop,TS val 381719336 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
20:48:42.539703 IP 192.168.250.10.22 > 192.168.250.1.49471: Flags [S.], seq 3352023725, ack 3387751539, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 8712093 ecr 381719336,nop,wscale 6], length 0
20:48:42.539782 IP 192.168.250.1.49471 > 192.168.250.10.22: Flags [.], ack 1, win 8235, options [nop,nop,TS val 381719336 ecr 8712093], length 0
20:48:42.540066 IP 192.168.250.1.49471 > 192.168.250.10.22: Flags [P.], seq 1:22, ack 1, win 8235, options [nop,nop,TS val 381719336 ecr 8712093], length 21
20:48:42.540078 IP 192.168.250.10.22 > 192.168.250.1.49471: Flags [.], ack 22, win 453, options [nop,nop,TS val 8712093 ecr 381719336], length 0
```

To filter out specific hosts, just use the standard `tcpdump` command line, e.g.:

```
$ tcpdump -n -r /tmp/w.pcap host 8.8.8.8 | head
reading from file /tmp/w.pcap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
20:48:47.595511 IP 192.168.250.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 10742, seq 1, length 64
20:48:47.603743 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.250.10: ICMP echo reply, id 10742, seq 1, length 64
20:48:48.597758 IP 192.168.250.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 10742, seq 2, length 64
20:48:48.606064 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.250.10: ICMP echo reply, id 10742, seq 2, length 64
20:48:49.600303 IP 192.168.250.10 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 10742, seq 3, length 64
20:48:49.610471 IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.250.10: ICMP echo reply, id 10742, seq 3, length 64
```

Or to exclude that host:

```
$ tcpdump -n -r /tmp/w.pcap not host 8.8.8.8 | head
reading from file /tmp/w.pcap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
20:48:38.498793 IP 192.168.250.10.22 > 192.168.250.1.49434: Flags [P.], seq 240912301:240912433, ack 2683174485, win 724, options [nop,nop,TS val 8711083 ecr 381715459], length 132
20:48:38.498968 IP 192.168.250.1.49434 > 192.168.250.10.22: Flags [.], ack 132, win 8183, options [nop,nop,TS val 381715490 ecr 8711083], length 0
20:48:40.945504 IP 192.168.250.10.68 > 192.168.250.254.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:0c:29:48:aa:d6, length 300
20:48:40.946062 IP 192.168.250.254.67 > 192.168.250.10.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300
20:48:41.045549 IP 192.168.250.10.33131 > 109.231.72.179.22: Flags [S], seq 724706181, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 8711720 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
20:48:42.539655 IP 192.168.250.1.49471 > 192.168.250.10.22: Flags [S], seq 3387751538, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 4,nop,nop,TS val 381719336 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
20:48:42.539703 IP 192.168.250.10.22 > 192.168.250.1.49471: Flags [S.], seq 3352023725, ack 3387751539, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 8712093 ecr 381719336,nop,wscale 6], length 0
20:48:42.539782 IP 192.168.250.1.49471 > 192.168.250.10.22: Flags [.], ack 1, win 8235, options [nop,nop,TS val 381719336 ecr 8712093], length 0
20:48:42.540066 IP 192.168.250.1.49471 > 192.168.250.10.22: Flags [P.], seq 1:22, ack 1, win 8235, options [nop,nop,TS val 381719336 ecr 8712093], length 21
20:48:42.540078 IP 192.168.250.10.22 > 192.168.250.1.49471: Flags [.], ack 22, win 453, options [nop,nop,TS val 8712093 ecr 381719336], length 0
```

You can do lists of hosts using `tcpdump -n -r /tmp/w.pcap host 8.8.8.8 or host 8.8.4.4` or similar.

Comment: Won't this group packets that have a certain IP address as either source or destination? For instance, when you talk about filtering out a specific host, 8.8.8.8 appears on both sides. But I need to filter not just by host but by host and direction.

Comment: But I added the `src` option, and that seemed to solve the issue.

Comment: Sure. You can use any `tcpdump` option.